# Can I develop from the BNA file of an existing hyperledger system?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I've been tasked with adding features to an existing hyperledger system. But all I've been given is the .bna file. I can clearly see it contains javascript source as well as models, but is this really enough to develop from? All my experience is going from .cto and .js files and configs to building the .bna archive. How do I go about doing that in reverse? Am I likely to run into problems because I'm missing something necessary not normally packaged in the .bna? Should I insist on getting the actual source tree that was used to build the .bna file? I already asked specifically for that and NOT the .bna file, but was ignored. Am I the ignorant one here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BNA file contains everything the networks needs to execute. The only things you are missing is things like build scripts, unit and system tests, documentation. So, I would keep trying to get the original source if you can, if you can't you *do* have enough to get going.

Comment: Also it may have been obvious to everyone but me, but you can rename a .bna to a .zip and extract all the files.